# Custom Post Type Category Link

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, loop

I have a loop of posts for a custom post type I built.

How can i call the link of the category/taxonomy for each post?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use [**`get_term_link();`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) for example:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'category');
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'category').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: what if i have 2 categories assigned @Bainternet ?.. can i stop the foreach after one time ?

Comment: Yeah you can, ask that as a new question and I'll show you.\

Comment: thanks man :) got lucky and found a good explenation - thanks anyhow and have a gr8 weekend